# rails 4 - iterate over results from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've built a little function in my rails 4 demo app model to do a sql query against all records found in a search. So it works like this:

```
def do_stuff(item_id)
  items = Widget.find_by item:id: item_id
  items.each do |t|
    #do stuff 
  end
end
```

The problem is when only one record is returned, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Widget:0xb93eaa44>
```

What's the best way to deal with cases where one or zero records are returned?

Comment: Your issue here is `find_by` this method returns the first result the query will show you this as it states `LIMIT 1`. you could use `find_all_by_item_id(item_id)` this is a dynamically generated method that will return a collection of objects using `where(item_id: item_id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
items = Widget.where(item_id: item_id)
```

This will always return a collection of records, regardless of the number of records found.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```
Widget.where(item_id: item_id).each do |w|
  # do stuff
end
```